# E490: No fold found in unix for vim

Tags: vim

I am vim newbie , fond of sublime-text

I want to fold the code base on indentation for perl script. I looked on web and found out that I need to make
the following setting into my vimrc file

```
      "fold setting"

      "folding settings
      set foldmethod=indent   "fold based on indent
      set foldnestmax=10      "deepest fold is 10 levels
      set nofoldenable        "dont fold by default
      set foldlevel=1         "this is just what i use
```

When I am trying to use 'za' cmd in vim its throwing `E490: No fold found` error

Sample perl code

```
        sub foo { #want to fold the code based on closing braces
            print "bar";
        }
```

Is I am missing something for vim to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this script inside `~/.vim/ftplugin/perl.vim` (create these files if they don't already exist).

```
function GetPerlFold()
    if getline(v:lnum) =~ '^\s*sub\s'
        return ">1"
    elseif getline(v:lnum) =~ '\}\s*$'
        let my_perlnum = v:lnum
        let my_perlmax = line("$")
        while (1)
            let my_perlnum = my_perlnum + 1
                if my_perlnum > my_perlmax
                    return "<1"
            endif
            let my_perldata = getline(my_perlnum)
            if my_perldata =~ '^\s*\(\#.*\)\?$'
                " do nothing
            elseif my_perldata =~ '^\s*sub\s'
                return "<1"
            else
                return "="
            endif
        endwhile
    else
        return "="
    endif
endfunction

setlocal foldexpr=GetPerlFold()
setlocal foldmethod=ex
```

This code is taken from [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Auto-fold_Perl_subs).

Make sure you remove `set foldmethod=indent` from you `.vimrc`

Now subs in perl should be properly folded.

Answer (score 1):

You have `set nofoldenable` in your .vimrc. This turns off folding. Filetype plugins don't turn on folding by default with `set foldenable`, they just assume `foldenable` is already set.

Remove that from your .vimrc as a first step. Then you will be using the "indent" foldmethod you are also setting in your .vimrc.

But Perl and some other languages also define folding rules based on syntax. To enable this for Perl, add something like this to your .vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType perl set foldmethod=syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set

```
set tabstop=N
set shiftwidth=N
```

along with

```
set foldmethod=indent
set foldenable
```

Where N is the number of spaces for your desired indentation

This makes sure vim knows what you mean by 'indent'

This should do what you want

Answer (score 0):

Add another line inside the parenthesis like so

```
 sub foo { #want to fold the code based on closing braces
     print "foo";
     print "bar";
 }
```

Place the cursor on any line **inside** the parenthesis and press `za`, it should now fold.

`:h 'foldmethod'`

```
|fold-indent|   indent      Lines with equal indent form a fold.
```

So only the indented lines inside the method will be indented. But, if there's only one line then there is no reason to fold as it would still take up one line anyway.